# Are all Relations statements? Or are all Statements relations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic, relations

Discrete math topic:

Statements, to my understanding, can be predicates or quantifiers. Predicates and quantifiers are relations of Logical systems. Statements can be negated, I think. So, statements seem to be relations.

However, statements (in literature), can be assertive or interrogative— *no where in discrete math have I heard of this topic (yet). Relations also seem to have this property:
For a relation R,
xRy can be asserted to a true value, or false value.
xRy can also be queried: xRy?

Are relations statements?

Where can I learn more about this topic, in Math (not literature)?

Comment: Statements are things possessing a truth value. Relations are subsets of a Cartesian product of sets; they are not statements themselves, but can be referred to in statements (such as the statement "given a relation R, xRy"). Quantifiers are the same — they are not statements, but can be parts of a statement.

Comment: Instead of saying "Relations are subsets of a Cartesian product of sets" I would say "Relations are _usually treated (or decoded) as_ subsets of a Cartesian product of sets" to avoid making any metaphysical identity claims.

Comment: I'm more concerned with mathematics than metaphysics... and mathematically, the statement is sound

Comment: Statements can express relations: "John is the son of Mary", "2 is less than 3".

Comment: In a symbolic language, like that of [predicate logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/) we have *symbols* for conncetive, quantifiers, predicates (unary, binary, etc.). Thus, using a binary predicate symbol $R(x,u)$ we may build the statement $\forall x \exists y R(x,y)$ that can formalize e.g. "for every number x there is a number y such that x is less-than y".

Comment: For sure, in antural language not every [statement](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/statement) express a relation: "I'm angry".

Comment: These comments are really insightful. Thank you guys.